# Magento Module - PHTML

Tags: magento2.3, phtml, helper

I need some help with a problem I have with a module, I know this is a newbie question but here i go.

```
<div class="field company <?= $block->isrequiered() ? 'required' : '' ?>">
```

How do I make this optional instead of required?

Answer (score 0):

This is [Ternary Condition](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-ternary-operator/)

> so basically if **$block->isrequiered()** getting then apply
> 'required' class otherwise black class add

If you don't want to add condition just remove condition

```
<div class="field company">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i do not understand what you mean.

Comment: Can't you delete the entire php block ('<?= $block->isrequiered() ? 'required' : '' ?>')? if it is not required, then it is optional right?

Comment: Yes this is simple condition let me explain in my answer